# Dockerfile with nginx, mysql, php7 and slimphp

Tags: php, mysql, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I need have problem with instance the vendor in my project.

My php dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update

# Install tools
RUN apt-get install -y \
    python-setuptools \
    software-properties-common \
    wget \
    git \
    curl \
    zip \
    vim

RUN echo 'deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie contrib' >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && apt-get install -y --force-yes libssl-dev curl  libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2-dev libicu-dev libmcrypt4 libmemcached11 openssl

#CONFIGURAÇÕES DO OPCACHE
RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache

#CONFIGURAÇÕES DO APCU
RUN pecl install apcu-5.1.5 && docker-php-ext-enable apcu

#LIBS EXTRAS
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath
RUN apt-get install -y libbz2-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install bz2
RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libicu-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install intl

#GD
RUN apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng16-16
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

#PDO
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

#sudo
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*    

VOLUME /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN pwd

# Allow Composer to be run as root
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

# Install composer
RUN wget https://getcomposer.org/download/1.5.5/composer.phar
RUN chmod +x composer.phar
RUN sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# Install libs/var_dumper
RUN mkdir -p /var/.composer
RUN composer global --no-interaction --working-dir=/var/.composer require slim/slim

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

I just wanna move the vendor folder to var/www/html

Docker-compose

```
nginx:
  container_name: nginx
  build: ./docker/nginx
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ./public:/var/www/html
  links:
        - php
        - mysql

php:
  container_name: php
  build: ./docker/php7
  volumes:
    - ./public:/var/www/html
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
  links:
    - mysql

mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=testedb
```

the vendor files are in /var/.composer and i can't acess them.
I wanna know how i build correctly the image to use the slim framework and the others images without errors.

Answer (score 1):

i consider [docker multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) a powerful mechanism, which you can use to achieve a lightweight container.

> With multi-stage builds, you use multiple FROM statements in your
>   Dockerfile. Each FROM instruction can use a different base, and each
>   of them begins a new stage of the build. You can selectively copy
>   artifacts from one stage to another, leaving behind everything you
>   don’t want in the final image.

composer is not slim, i cant see why it should reside at your final image. if i were you, i would create a composer stage, where i copy the project and run `composer install`. then i would copy the `vendor` directory as an artifact on to the final stage, which wont have composer installed at all. heres a basic example:

```
#create vendor:
FROM prooph/composer:7.3 as vendor-installer
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . .
RUN composer install

#final stage
FROM php:7.2.1-fpm
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY --from vendor-installer /var/www/html/vendor vendor
```

**EDIT**

you will also have to exclude the vendor dir from the volume statement in the `docker-compose.yml`, so it wont get overwritten:

```
php:
  container_name: php
  build: ./docker/php7
  volumes:
    - ./public:/var/www/html
    - /var/www/html/vendor
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i understand and test your code.
But do the same thing, in the finals don't copy the vendor folder to www/html.

I guess my docker-compose.yml was wrong.

Comment: @BrenoSobral thats probably because of the volumes. you have to exclude it out. i showed you how.

Comment: I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli   

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.json /var/www/html

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www/html

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN composer install

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - php-data:/var/www/html/vendor/
      - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:           
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: testedb
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
  php-data:
```

I do that, creating 3 volumes and put vendor in php-data

Comment: interesting... but then you have to manually install the vendor dir yourself, dont you?

Comment: No, its create automatically, check in my github, but is in portuguese.
I can translate after.

Comment: hi @Breno that looks good. you have composer installed in your container, which isnt the case in my solution. i thought mine could help you achieving more lightweight container. good luck anyway,